# Echoing string and variable in vim script

Tags: vim

Have the following simple function in a vim script:

```
function me#Tabwidth(width)
    let &tabstop = a:width
    let &shiftwidth = a:width
    set expandtab
    echom "Tab width set to " + a:width
endfunction
```

The function is being called like this in the vimrc file.

```
command -nargs=* Tabwidth :call me#Tabwidth(<f-args>)
```

When called by typing "Tabwidth 2" only the value of the variable is being echoed out, but not the string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vim script, string concatenation is done with `.` operator. Try like this:

```
echom "Tab width set to " . a:width
```

If `a:width` is a number, it will be automatically converted.